# In which episodes does Madara Uchiha make an appearance?

Tags: naruto

I wanted to know *all* episodes where Madara Uchiha makes an appearance, but I can't find any answers anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Does it have to be the anime or would the manga suffice? The Naruto Wiki entry for Madara (https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha#References) has a bunch of citations for the stuff it talks about but it references the manga not the anime, I don't think the references would be a complete list since its not citing every chapter he appears just where specific pieces of info are from (and he isn't even necessarily in chapters he's mentioned) but it would be a place to start if you wanted to compile a list for yourself

Answer (score 4):

According to [fandom wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha) (and to me who checked that he was actually there), Madara's first appearence in anime is in [*Naruto: Shippuden* episode 130](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/The_Man_Who_Became_God). If we follow the main plot, he appears in Itachi's history lesson to Sasuke in [episode 136](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/The_Light_and_Dark_of_the_Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan). Afterwards, he takes on his role of main antagonist starting from [episode 321](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Reinforcements_Arrive). From then onwards (although probably not after episode 479) you may expect Madara to be in almost all episodes. I won't be watching those episodes to list the ones where Madara isn't, because the sheer amount of time required (70 hours of watch time, give or take) makes it unreasonable. For similar reasons, I won't make a thorough research to see if Madara may appear in fillers between episodes 131 and 320.

Madara also appears in the special OVA [*Naruto Shippūden: Ultimate Ninja Storm Generations OVA Hashirama Senju vs Madara Uchiha*](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Naruto_Shipp%C5%ABden:_Ultimate_Ninja_Storm_Generations_OVA_Hashirama_Senju_vs_Madara_Uchiha), i.e. a cutscene in the aforementioned videogame.